# How is it possible to position a bokeh widget?

Tags: python, widget, positioning, bokeh

My aim is to position a vertical slider beside a figure in a grid of 2 horizontal arranged figures and I have no idea how to manage the arrangement in bokeh. Do you have any advice? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can put one vertical slider beside a grid of 2 horizontal arranged figures:

```
from bokeh.io import show, hplot
from bokeh.models import Slider
from bokeh.plotting import figure, gridplot
p1 = figure(plot_width=300,plot_height=200)
p2 = figure(plot_width=300,plot_height=200)
slider = Slider(value=0,start=-1,end=1,step=0.1, orientation = "vertical")
aa = gridplot([[p1,p2]])
show(hplot(aa,slider))
```

The output is:
[image]

Comment: I am glad I could help. What I would like to know is a way to resize the slider controllers. I tried to put two sliders on the side and there was a large separation between them. I would love to have them closer together. Maybe by specifying a width or height.